# bootstrap datepicker in three different scenario via css

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, datepicker

How to set a color for  bootstrap datepicker  in three different scenarios when it is inactive state(disable) and active state(selectable) and current date I need set color for all three in hover ,active, focused via css.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this: For disabled:

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.disabled, .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.disabled:hover {
    background: none;
    color: #777777;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

And active:

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.active, .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.active:hover {
    background-color: #337ab7;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```